# compare sqlite strings

Tags: android, date, sqlite, comparison

I have a problem and I can't figure out whats causing it.  I have a sqlite3 DB for android running.  The app places some date values as text in a column.  Now I want to get all entries from - lets say - this month.  So normally I would do something like this:

SELECT * FORM myTable WHERE date > '2011-10-01'

However my resultset consists of all entries.  The date coloum is formatted the same way - so there is no problem.  I just have no idea, what is causing this strange output.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, what happens if you change that to:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE date like '2011-10-01%'
```

Comment: Then I get an empty result set - my first entry is for the 4th of october ... thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't help, sorry.

Comment: This works in all my Android apps. There's something wrong with your database and/or its content.

Comment: Thanks for the hint - it works without the dashed - but not with them.  This is so strange, and its really bothering me, what the problem is.  of course I could do it without the dashed and rewrite some code, but I wanna know whats the underlying problem.

Comment: Please show create statement of myTable, one result of that tuple (row/column) and the real select statement (form is no valid keyword). And to make it clear - you're working on an Android device/emulator (what SDK version? What target?) with Eclipse/Java?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your problem and the results show that it actually should work like you tried.
At least with a normal installation of sqlite3 that is:

```
sqlite> select * from myTable;
2011-09-01
2011-08-01
2011-11-01
2011-10-02
sqlite> select * from myTable where date > "2011-10-01";
2011-11-01
2011-10-02
```

So my guess is that you have an issue with your database format or your query does not look like the one you posted. Aside from the FORM instead of FROM which I guess is a typo.b

Comment: Thats actally an exact copy of what I do.  Unfortunately i use a android implementation of Sqlite nad it seems to have a problem with the '-', cause after I deleted them, it works fine.  However I can't see why it is having so much problems with the '-'. I still would like to use my old date format, otherwise I have to rewrite some code (I don't like that ;) ).